# How to Handel 401 error (Unauthorized) on ODataModel in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to Authenticate the ODataModel by passing Dynamic Username and Password.

Here is a example:

```
new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(serviceURI,true , userName, userPwd);
```

Here when i passing the wrong username and password i am getting the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

How can i handle this error on ODataModel.

Answer (score 0):

As I hope this is only for testing purposes, and you do not plan to specify a username and password in the source code for everyone to see, you may try if the `requestFailed` event handler catches this upfront.

Otherwise you may use a simple `try/catch` block and handle the exception gracefully

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Now I am handling the error by attachMetadataFailed(). 

But here i am facing another issue. First time when i try to login with invalid username and password i am getting error. but when i try to enter the correct username and password i am getting the same error.

when i try to look into the console my oDatamodel is requesting the same URL as prevoius URL.
Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Ya i tried this. Now i am able to login. But is there any way to do this from programming.